# Decay effect/texture

Tags: texturing, materials

Could anybody help me with achieving the same effect in blender as in the following image? 
[image]

But with both ends of the the gray material as noisy as the bottom one.
It's supposed to be a tooth decay.

More details:

[image]

And this is what I have in Blender at the moment:

[image]

Current stage of the tooth after the responses: 
(using another tooth)
[image]

Comment: Can you please add more? I am not quite sure what you are asking.

Comment: Edited the question with more images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear what you are trying to achieve, is this supposed to be like a decay "wave" advancing from one end to the other? How will you be rendering it, Cycles?

If in cycles you could easily achieve this by animating a gradient texture and using it as a mask to drive a *Shader Mix* node using the *Factor* socket.

You could then make your Tooth" shader and "decay" shader to your liking and mix it with the setup above. Optionally add a noise texture to make it have a more irregular pattern as shown above.

[image: Tooth decay animation]

[image: Tooth node setup]

Comment: Very nice, but I believe from Bullet93's post history and the images he displayed that he intends to use BR, not Cycles.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for :D. I added a picture of what i got after adding these to my nodes. The only thing i'm missing is the smooth transition between the two. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is change the interpolation method for the color ramp node from the pull-down menu. Add a few more nodes to control how tight or wide the transition gradient will be.

Answer (score 2):

### Idle Chit-chat

The best way I could think of doing things is to create two separate meshes: the tooth and the decay. Using my method, I created this:

[image]

### Teeth Creation

I started by modeling a simple tooth. I included the mesh for this image, but deleted it later. Do not worry about it. I also set shading to *Smooth* in the *Tools* bar. I then added a material and set the Diffuse color to hex FFF2FE. I did not change anything else in the material.

[image]

After that, I added a sphere. I set the shading to smooth. I moved it down to Z: -1.4334 and scaled it so X, Y, and Z were all 1.189. This makes it so just some of the sphere is visible near the gunky area in the reference photo. I added both a *Subdivision surface* and *Displace* Object modifier. I set the settings to these:

[image]

**Important!** Before you can set the settings in the *Displace* modifier, click *+ New* to get a new texture. Name it "Disp."

Next, I went to the *Textures* tab in the *Properties panel*. Make sure that [image] is selected at the top of the tab. Select *Displace* from the top drop down menu and *Disp* if it isn't already selected in the next drop down menu. If it is not already set, set the *Type:* to *Clouds*.

[image]

With the sphere still selected, go to the *Materials* tab and add a new material. Set the Diffuse color to hex C29F75. Change the *Specular intensity:* to *.1*.

### Lighting and World setup

Move the lamp infront of the tooth. I used X: *0.0194096*, Y: *-4.1363487*, and Z: *2.4681318*. In the *Object Data* Properties panel tab, set *Samples:* to *5*. Go to the *World* tab. Set the *Horizon Color:* to hex 595A66. Check *Environment Lighting*. Set the *Energy:* to *.4*, and in the drop down menu, select *Sky Color*.

### Last Words

I assumed here that you were using BR. If you use Cycles, refer to Duarte Farrajota Ramos's answer. I might tweak the lighting to get a better result. Finally, here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, but i need it to be the same object, like the surface of the object