# Is possible to control quantity of texture? (Python)

Tags: python, texturing, uv

I have this sort of stone and I want it to have some lichens on the top but I want to control te quantity of lichens that is on the stone. 
Texture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofi2X.jpg

For that I've already this texture overlaping twice and I'm using the mapping node to control this. Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjowC.jpg

Using Python I'm trying to like simulate the aging and growth (more and bigger liquens) controlling the mapping node and my question is, is there any other way that this can be accomplished? Kind of controlling Uvs and adding this texture a few times?Image processing? Thank you.

Comment: I think you have the wrong lichen texture type. You should have a large continuous texture and then animate some sort of mask to get more or less amount of lichen covering the stone. You will have a hard time getting a continuously covered surface from a non continuous texture

Comment: Thank you, but how would you do that? How do you control the quantity that you show? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Just use another (possibly procedural) texture as a mask in a *Color Mix* node as mixing factor. See if this helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52344/decay-effect-texture/52347#52347 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79386/image-texture-to-partially-mask-part-of-material/79397#79397